# Issues with ResponseEntity in RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have two Microservices, say Microservice1 makes call to Microservice2 using RestTemplate.

The handler method on Microservice2 is this.

```
 @GetMapping("/careerRoles")
 public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getRole(@RequestParam(value = 
   "roleName", required = false) String roleName,
 @RequestParam(value = "domain", required = false) String domain,
 @RequestParam("proficiencyLevel") String proficiencyLevel,
 @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
 @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false) Integer limit) {
   Map<String, Object> query = new HashMap<>();
   Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<>();

   if (page == null && limit == null) {
       page = 1;
       limit = 10;
   }
   query.put("page", page);
   query.put("limit", limit);
   List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

   try {
       if (roleName == null) {
           query.put("proficiencyLevel", proficiencyLevel);

           roles = this.roleService.getRolesByProficiencyLevel(proficiencyLevel, page, limit);
       } else {
           query.put("proficiencyLevel", proficiencyLevel);
           query.put("roles", roleName);
           roles = this.roleService.getRolesByNameAndProficiencyLevel(roleName, proficiencyLevel, page, limit);

       }

       json.put("error", null);
       json.put("query", query);
       json.put("result", roles);
       return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(json, HttpStatus.OK);

   } catch (RoleNotFoundException e) {
       json.put("error", e.getMessage());
       json.put("query", query);
       json.put("result", roles);
       return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(json, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
   }

 }
```

The calling code in Microservice1 is this.

```
@GetMapping("careerRole")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> getCareerRole(
  @RequestParam(value = "roleName", required = false) String roleName,
  @RequestParam(value = "domain", required = false) String domain,
  @RequestParam("proficiencyLevel") String proficiencyLevel,
  @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
  @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false) Integer limit) {

   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("Hello World!", 
     headers);
   UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
           .fromUriString(uri)
           // Add query parameter
           .queryParam("roleName",roleName)
           .queryParam("proficiencyLevel", proficiencyLevel);
  Map<String,Object> map = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.toUriString(), 
    Map.class);
   return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(map,HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}
```

The code is working and returns JSON as expected when I send this to Microservice1 listening on port 8081

```
http://localhost:8081/api/v1/careerRoles?proficiencyLevel=Novice
```

However, if I send two request parameters like this, the code fails.

```
http://localhost:8081/api/v1/careerRoles?roleName=Java Developer&proficiencyLevel=Novice
```

However, if I use Postman to directly access Microservice 2 with both the preceding GET requests, results are comming as expected.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: could you add a failure stack trace?

Comment: Use urlencoder.encode() method to encode the complete url. I think the space between java and developer is causing the issue

Comment: Actually decode() did the trick. The request parameter was in form roleName=Java%20Developer. After decode, it became roleName=Java Developer (with space) and it worked.
Strange though.

Comment: Actually I was confuse between client code and server one anyways I think my hint worked.. Gr8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced this issue before.

The space between java and developer might create problem so decode it before proceeding.